# CSS tag to increase font size

Tags: css

Is there any method to create a css tag which increases the font size? Something like:

```
<style>
p {
    font-size: 100%;
}

lrg {
    font-size: +40%;
}
</style>

<p>Hi <lrg>Tom</lrg>!</p>
```

In the above example, the default text size is 100% but the text size of that inside the  tag is 140% (100+40).

Is there any way to receive similar results??

Comment: Please tell me if the question isn't clear enough and I will edit it...

Comment: Note HTML5 standardizes [custom elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#dfn-custom-element), but they must contain an hyphen. So `<lrg>` is invalid.

Comment: @Oriol How about <larger-than-the-rest-text> ?  :P

Comment: Yes, I think `<larger-than-the-rest-text>` should be valid.

Comment: CSS does not have tags. Perhaps you mean "property value". Or perhaps you mean a new HTML tag? That's best avoided. Instead, use "classes"; I suggest you bone up on them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `em` units:

```css
span {
    font-size: 1.4em; /* 40% bigger than the parent */
}
```

```html
<p>Hi <span>Tom</span>!</p>
```

Comment: Best practice is generally considered to use `%` to set the base body font size and then use `em` thereafter on inner content. This has best browser compatibility (especially with older browser versions) and development convenience.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do is the following:

```
<style>
p {
    font-size: 100%; /* This is actually redundant as it does not change the font size */
}

.lrg {
    font-size: 140%; /* 40% increase */
}
</style>
```

Then use it like this:

```
<p>Hi <span class="lrg>Tom</span>!</p>
```

Think about it this way: the percentages *multiply* and setting a value above `100%` increases the previously set font size, while setting a value below `100%` decreases the previously set font size.

Same goes for using `em` units. Use a number above `1.0em` to increase and number below `1.0em` to decrease font size.

Comment: What if I use the same CSS file for multiple pages but want to specify <lrg> on only one?? I would want it to add 40% to what is pre-defined in the Style sheet...

Comment: That's not "correct", because there is no "lrg" tag in HTML/5.

Comment: @torazaburo Thank you for your comment, but HTML5 actually *does* support custom tags through Web Components. But since the author probably isn't using them, I have made an edit to my post, so the answer is now correct.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, consider using `font-size: larger`. However, you cannot randomly invent your own new HTML tags. That's what **classes** are for:

```
/* Define a CSS class that makes the font larger */
.lrg { font-size: larger; }

<!-- Use a span tag with the new class -->
<p>Hi <span class="lrg">Tom</span>!</p>
```